# Xcode 11 using organizer to upload IPA fails

Tags: xcode11, itmstransporter

I recently upgraded to Catalina and Xcode 11.

Now when I try to upload an archive from the organizer, I get a simple error saying «"Error Domain=WorkerErrorDomain Code=-10000 "An error occurred uploading to the App Store."»

Since this isn't really an error message, I tried to use `xcrun altool` to upload the ipa.

That's when things get interesting. This fails with the following error:

```
Java 1.5 or Java 1.6 is required. Currently, java is the default java version. Please upgrade.
```

Java 1.6 is ancient! There's not even a downloadable package available for Catalina.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

This is the output of the command line tool (redacted for paths and secret-codes):

```
Using tool '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Resources/DTAppAnalyzerExtractor'.
'DTAppAnalyzerExtractor': self.executablePath: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Resources/DTAppAnalyzerExtractor
Launching: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AppStoreService.framework/Resources/DTAppAnalyzerExtractor --input-dir /var/folders/bj/xxxxx/T/myipa.ipa --output-file /var/folders/bj/xxxxx/T/DTAppAnalyzerExtractorOutput-xxxxx.zip
Web service call (validateSoftwareSPIUsage) result: (null)
Using template named: purple-metadata-template
Sending request to iTunesTransporter...
Command: /usr/local/itms/bin/iTMSTransporter
Arguments: -m upload -u 'myusername@mydomain.com' -vp json -TxHeaders xxxxx== -sessionid xxxxx -sharedsecret xxxxx -f '/var/folders/bj/xxxxx/T/xxxxx/xxxx.itmsp' -indicator true -v eXtreme -Dtransporter.client='altool' -Dtransporter.client.version='4.00 (1181)'
Java 1.5 or Java 1.6 is required. Currently, java is the default java version. Please upgrade.
Error:
Java 1.5 or Java 1.6 is required. Currently, java is the default java version. Please upgrade.
Out:
Errors: (null)
*** Error: Errors uploading '/Library/Documents/myapp.ipa': (
    "Error Domain=WorkerErrorDomain Code=-10000 \"An error occurred uploading to the App Store.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred uploading to the App Store., NSLocalizedFailureReason=An error occurred uploading to the App Store.}"
```

Comment: Did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The culprit was a directory on my system named "/usr/local/itms/" which had a very old iTMSTransporter from 2008 in it. Xcode using that old tool for some reason. After I deleted that whole directory and relaunched Xcode, it worked!

Credit goes to @BigZaphod on twitter! (This is a direct quote)

Comment: Awesome! This error had been a frustrating journey - especially since XCode gave no detail whatsoever. Totally solved the problem for me! Many thanks!

Comment: I've had this problem twice over the last few years, and I can't remember how I solved it last time but this definitely fixed it for me with Xcode 12 beta 5, where beta 4 was uploading fine yesterday. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and check "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "Automatic Proxy Configuration", other proxy options cannot be checked. And finally uncheck "SOCKS Proxy" option, this resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use`xcodebuild` is better

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportOptionsPlist /pathTo/ExportOptionsUpload.plist -archivePath /pathTo/App.xcarchive
```

`ExportOptionsUpload.plist` include

```
<key>destination</key>
<string>upload</string>
```

See detail by

```
man xcodebuild
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how this would help with my problem. Will xcodebuild upload the IPA to appstoreconnect? As far as I understand, it just builds the IPA?

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes?language=objc)   Since Xcode 10,`xcodebuild` add New Features